# in the below python code what isthe use of ' \ ' symbol

Tags: python, python-3.x

in below code what is the use of ' \ '
I tried without that i got an error ,I am new to python please help me

```
while left_index < right_index:
   
    list_of_chars[left_index], list_of_chars[right_index] = \
        list_of_chars[right_index], list_of_chars[left_index]
    
    left_index  += 1
    right_index -= 1
```

Comment: Escape character, or line continuation.

Answer (score 0):

The `\` character allows you to break a lone line in to two lines. It specifies that the following line is the continuation of the current line and not a new statement.